# Async Event Driven Programming with Spring -Reactor for Different JVM

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, event-bus, project-reactor

I am well aware of Spring event driven programming using project reactor which uses 
EventBus.

If I have all the components(consumers and producers) reside in same JVM then they 
can exchange events and this model works fine.

Can I use this Spring Event Driven approach to communicate between Components if 
they are in different JVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that reactor 3 does not have reactor-bus project any more, at least for now.

Anyway for distributed systems it is common approach to use message brokers, such as RabbitMQ, Kafka and much more.

Currently reactor Kafka support is in active development and the project resides https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka.

Hope this can help.